# Is the following information sufficient to guarantee a global maximum at the corner of some interval?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Suppose one has a continuous and twice differentiable function $h(x)$, defined on the interval $(\underline{x}(a), x^*]$, where $a \geq 0$ is a parameter. By definition, it holds that

$h'(x^*) = 0$, whereas $h''(x^*)< 0$ if and only if the parameter $a$ is "sufficiently" close to $0$.

Moreover, it holds that $\lim_{a\downarrow 0} \underline{x}(a) = x^*$.

My question is the following: is this information sufficient to guarantee that $h(x)$ must have a global maximum at $x^*$ over the relevant range $(\underline{x}(a), x^*]$ if $a$ is sufficiently close to zero?

If not, can a counter-example be provided?

This property would be very convenient for an applied research paper (not in maths obviously), but I'm not really sure how to prove it (if it is even true).

Comment: Does $h$ depend on $a$? If yes, please make this clear in the formulation.

Comment: Yes, in general $h$ depends on $a$. Isn't this is already implied by the fact that $h$ is continuous, and that $h''(x^*) <0$ if and only if $a$ is sufficiently small?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $$h_a''(x^\ast) < 0 \quad\forall\ 0<a<\bar{a}$$
Then for every $a \in (0, \bar{a})$ there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that
$$h_a''(x) < 0 \quad\forall\ x \in (x^\ast - \epsilon, x^\ast]$$
Now the problem is, that $\epsilon$ depends on a and $\liminf_{a\to 0} \epsilon(a)$ might be $0$. This fact could be exploited to generate a counter-example.

Comment: Thanks, I see the problem. So in some sense, one would have to show that either $\epsilon(a)$ is bounded away from zero for every $a \in (0, \overline{a})$, or that $\epsilon(a)$ converges "more slowly" to zero than $\underline{x}(a)$ converges to $x^*$, as $a \downarrow 0$. Whatever the latter precisely means.

Comment: @MartinObradovits did you find a counter-example? If so, do you mind sharing the result?

Answer (score 0):

To provide some preliminary thoughts:

Intuitively, I think that the property should hold. Namely, let $\overline{a}>0$ such that for all $a < \overline{a}, h''(x^*) < 0$. This means that $h(x)$ will be locally concave around $x^*$.

But then, as the lower boundary of the relevant interval $\underline{x}(a)$ converges to $x^*$ as $a \downarrow 0$, by continuity it must hold eventually (for sufficiently low $a$) that $h''(x) < 0$ for all $x \in (\underline{x}(a),x^*]$.

I'm just not sure whether this "proof" is too sloppy... am I overlooking something?